# Call to undefined function printer_open()

Tags: php, printing

I am trying to connect to my printer which is on another machine through this code

```
     $handle = printer_open("\\\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\\Canon MF4320-4350");
     if($handle)
     echo "connected";
     else
     echo "not connected";
```

and getting the error

```
    Fatal error: Call to undefined function printer_open() in C:\wamp\www\print\index.php on line 3
```

I have installed the php_printer.dll but it is not showing it under `phpinfo()`. Using PHP version 5.3.0

how can i connect to the printer and make my `printer_open()` method work??

Comment: Have you enabled the extension in php.ini?

Comment: Did you restart your webserver?

Comment: Did you restart apache? Did you check the logs for any errors?

Comment: yes i have enabled the extension in php.ini and restarted my apache too.. no luck :(

Comment: Not much help but I've never once managed to get the printer stuff working in php for sending straight to a printer.  Its so bad I've resorted to creating pdf's and auto opening them for users to just do ctrl+p :(

Comment: so printing with php is not a feasible approach??

Comment: I'm sure it works for some people or someone perhaps. Just I've never been able to get it working and I spent an insane amount of time attempting it.  In the end I came up with other solutions like users having to click print on stuff instead of auto printing and stuff like email to fax rather than direct spool to fax machine.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using PHP 5.3/ 5.4/ 5.5 in WAMP, here is how you setup printer.

1. Go to this link:http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/printer/0.1.0-dev/
2. Download the zip for your version. First try with ts. If it does not work, try nts.
3. Unzip and copy the php_printer.dll file. Paste here: C:\wamp\bin\php(phpyourversion)\ext . Note: (phpyourversion) will be like php5.5.12 depending on your version.
4. Find the loaded php.ini file. Use phpinfo or Wamp menu to find it. Look online for more help.
5. Paste this at the end of the file: extension=php_printer.dll
6. Restart server.
7. Create a file with the following code and test it:

   `<?php

   $printer_name = "Your Printer Name exactly as it is"; 
   $handle = printer_open($printer_name);
   printer_start_doc($handle, "My Document");
   printer_start_page($handle);
   $font = printer_create_font("Arial", 100, 100, 400, false, false, false, 0);
   printer_select_font($handle, $font);
   printer_draw_text($handle, 'This sentence should be printed.', 100, 400);
   printer_delete_font($font);
   printer_end_page($handle);
   printer_end_doc($handle);
   printer_close($handle);`
8. If the above does not work, try with nts version of the php_printer.dll file as mentioned in step two. remember to restart server after deleting the previous file, pasting the new file.

Comment: Wow! your code is working well. can you please tell me one more thing, How can I print a barcode with this code?

Comment: Never use an NTS DLL in WAMPServer.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem. This is what I have figured out so far.

1. Make sure that you have a php_printer.dll matching your php compile version in your extension folder ( php/ext/ ). Use this [link](http://likepie.net/2012/php_printer-dll-and-php-5-3-9/) for downloading the file.
2. add the following in your php.ini file:

   ```
   printer.default_printer=PHP_INI_ALL
   extension=php_printer.dll
   ```

The errors have disappeared but the file is still not printing.

Comment: yea.. i ve achieved this too.. but no lead in printing yet :(

Comment: Please make it more clear the solution.Please mention where we have to copy php_printer.dll.