# php_printer() Not Working

Tags: php, printing

Hi I am working on an application and finally it leads to print a bill in the hp laserjet cp 1025 printer.I searched many topics and included php_printer.dll in the ect folder.

I am getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function printer_open()

Can you please any one help?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Hi, once check these links... they may help you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338132/call-to-undefined-function-printer-open

                                         http://board.issociate.de/thread/201847/Call_to_undefined_function_printer_open().html

Comment: I used that extension once and I had to build it against a particular version of PHP turned out to be a lot of hassle

Comment: Hi , Thanks for you response , I tried the above option too,,but the same error

Comment: I am using Apache Version  Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.5.30

Any one suggest the right php_printer.dll please?