# php_printer() Not Working on Cpanel Server Side

Tags: php, dll, php-printer

i am doing web application based on php , 
while i am forcing my content to network printer
the following error was happening..

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function printer_open()
>   in E:\xampp\htdocs\print\index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\print\index.php on line 3

my codes :

```
$php_content='Test Print';

$handle = printer_open("\\\\192.168.2.4\\EPSON L365 Series");

printer_write($handle, $php_content);

printer_close($handle);
```

I am adding `php_printer.dll` file to `xampp/php/ext` folder 
and adding  the `extension=php_printer` into  `php.ini` file

After restarting my xampp server its working fine on locally.

Same code I was executed on my Cpanel server  HTTP ERROR 500  was showing.

Kindly give the solution for this..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call to undefined function printer\_open()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338132/call-to-undefined-function-printer-open)

Comment: Your CPanel Server is I assume a hosted Server and not one you control yourself?