# Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\printer_open() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, printing

I tried to make an application with laravel that would print directly to the printer. and when the end of the process to print, I get an error "Call to undefined the function App \ Http \ Controllers \ printer_open ()"

my code:

```
 $print  = printer_open();

        printer_set_option($print, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW"); // mode disobek (gak ngegulung kertas)
        //ukuran lebar
        printer_set_option($print, PRINTER_RESOLUTION_Y, 940);
        printer_start_doc($print);
        printer_start_page($print);

        $font = printer_create_font("Arial", 45, 10, PRINTER_FW_NORMAL, false, false, false, 0);
        printer_select_font($print, $font);
        printer_draw_text($print, $nama_instansi,$var_magin_left,0);

        $pen = printer_create_pen(PRINTER_PEN_SOLID, 2, "000000");
        printer_select_pen($print, $pen);
        printer_draw_line($print, $var_magin_left, 55, 700, 55);

        // Header Bon
        $font = printer_create_font("Arial", 25, 10, PRINTER_FW_NORMAL, false, false, false, 0);
        printer_select_font($print, $font);
        printer_draw_text($print, $hari, $var_magin_left, 70);
        printer_draw_text($print, ", ",75, 70);
        printer_draw_text($print, date("d/m/Y"),90, 70);
        printer_draw_text($print, " - ",200, 70);
        printer_draw_text($print, date("H:i"),220, 70);

        $font = printer_create_font("Arial", 38, 11, PRINTER_FW_NORMAL, false, false, false, 0);
        printer_select_font($print, $font);
        printer_draw_text($print, "Nomor Antrian ".$loket, 160, 130);   

        $font = printer_create_font("Arial", 98, 37, PRINTER_FW_NORMAL, false, false, false, 0);
        printer_select_font($print, $font);
        printer_draw_text($print, $no_antrian, 210, 170);


        $pen = printer_create_pen(PRINTER_PEN_SOLID, 2, "000000");
        printer_select_pen($print, $pen);
        printer_draw_line($print, $var_magin_left, 280, 700, 280);

        $font = printer_create_font("Arial", 20, 12, PRINTER_FW_NORMAL, false, false, false, 0);
        printer_select_font($print, $font);
        printer_draw_text($print, "\"Budayakan Antri Untuk Kenyamanan \n Bersama\"", $var_magin_left, 290);
        printer_draw_text($print, "Terimakasih Atas Kunjungan Anda", 100, 310);

        $row +=350;
        printer_draw_text($print, ". ", 0, $row);

        printer_delete_font($font);

        printer_end_page($print);
        printer_end_doc($print);

        printer_start_doc($print);
        printer_start_page($print);
        printer_close($print);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call to undefined function printer\_open()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338132/call-to-undefined-function-printer-open)

Answer (score 0):

put the code into a function then call it, like:-
      public function printer_open()
         {
        printer_set_option($print, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW"); // mode disobek (gak ngegulung kertas)
        //ukuran lebar
        printer_set_option($print, PRINTER_RESOLUTION_Y, 940);
        printer_start_doc($print);
        printer_start_page($print);

```
    $font = printer_create_font("Arial", 45, 10, PRINTER_FW_NORMAL, false, false, false, 0);
    printer_select_font($print, $font);
    printer_draw_text($print, $nama_instansi,$var_magin_left,0);

    $pen = printer_create_pen(PRINTER_PEN_SOLID, 2, "000000");
    printer_select_pen($print, $pen);
    printer_draw_line($print, $var_magin_left, 55, 700, 55);

    // Header Bon
    $font = printer_create_font("Arial", 25, 10, PRINTER_FW_NORMAL, false, false, false, 0);
    printer_select_font($print, $font);
    printer_draw_text($print, $hari, $var_magin_left, 70);
    printer_draw_text($print, ", ",75, 70);
    printer_draw_text($print, date("d/m/Y"),90, 70);
    printer_draw_text($print, " - ",200, 70);
    printer_draw_text($print, date("H:i"),220, 70);

    $font = printer_create_font("Arial", 38, 11, PRINTER_FW_NORMAL, false, false, false, 0);
    printer_select_font($print, $font);
    printer_draw_text($print, "Nomor Antrian ".$loket, 160, 130);   

    $font = printer_create_font("Arial", 98, 37, PRINTER_FW_NORMAL, false, false, false, 0);
    printer_select_font($print, $font);
    printer_draw_text($print, $no_antrian, 210, 170);


    $pen = printer_create_pen(PRINTER_PEN_SOLID, 2, "000000");
    printer_select_pen($print, $pen);
    printer_draw_line($print, $var_magin_left, 280, 700, 280);

    $font = printer_create_font("Arial", 20, 12, PRINTER_FW_NORMAL, false, false, false, 0);
    printer_select_font($print, $font);
    printer_draw_text($print, "\"Budayakan Antri Untuk Kenyamanan \n Bersama\"", $var_magin_left, 290);
    printer_draw_text($print, "Terimakasih Atas Kunjungan Anda", 100, 310);

    $row +=350;
    printer_draw_text($print, ". ", 0, $row);

    printer_delete_font($font);

    printer_end_page($print);
    printer_end_doc($print);

    printer_start_doc($print);
    printer_start_page($print);
    printer_close($print);
}
$print  = printer_open();
```